# Excel Barcode Scanning Macro

Tags: excel, barcode-scanner, vba

I deal with a large number of unique products (10,000+ per year on my own) and I am looking to optimise Excel to make my job more efficient. I have a USB barcode scanner and want to implement this into my process.

My suppliers send me a large spreadsheet with product info, such as barcode number and other product details. I also recieve samples of the product and need to register them within the system, and cross reference them with the spreadsheet.

I am looking for a macro which: when it recieves an input from the scanner, searches and navigates within the spreadsheet to the row where the product is, and if the same barcode has a second scan within 3-5 seconds, fills in the date in column x, and if column x is an occupied cell, fills in the date in column y.

This will allow me to both search for the product without filling in the date (not double scanning) for general lookups, but also to check the product in and out with the date.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: The problem with a macro is that you have to activate it somehow, which is an extra step. Are you planning to scan a ton of these in a row?

Comment: @theMayer That seems to be the biggest problem. There will be 50+ in a row so activating it for the first scan will be fine, but for every single scan is an issue.

Comment: I worked on an excel file to capture barcode scans. My use case had about 100 different products per box, some in multiple quantities. I found that just scanning to a column and processing the data afterward was the easiest approach. The problem with this was that unskilled users can mess it up. Really Excel is not the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, the fact that this question relates to barcode scanning could be disregarded - barcode scanners are implemented simply as keyboard devices that 'type' the number scanned (some append 'enter' on the end, some don't, and some are configurable).

So the answer to your question need not be in any way specific to the scanning of barcodes. It pretty much just needs an `InputBox` that takes a number and then uses that number in the `MATCH` function.

e.g.

```
code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")
matchedCell = match(code, productRange, 0)
matchedCell.Offset(0,2) = Now
```

where `productRange` is the range of cells that your product listing takes up.

edit:

To start with, follow a tutorial like this one: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html

You should end up with a button on your form that, when clicked, will put the word "hello" in cell A1.

Once you have this working, replace the 'hello' code with the lines I suggested above and you should be well on your way.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Paul. How would I implement this to my spreadsheets?

Comment: @HiFi Sounds like you are looking for somebody to just write the macro for you. There are many sites for hiring developers, this is not one of them.

Comment: @Enrico It may seem like this, but I am trying to learn how to do it myself!